# Fetch MongoDB\Driver\Cursor objects directly into specified class

Tags: php, mongodb

Currently, each document fetched from Mongo DB goes to a `stdClass` object. I would like to load this directly into my own custom class instead.

The class

```
class TestClass {
    private $id;
    private $class;

    function __construct($id, $name) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->class = $class;
    }
}
```

The code

```
$m = MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://<user>:<pass>@<host>/<db>');
$query = MongoDB\Driver\Query(['name' => 'TestFirst']);
// I tried adding the following line, but it says that the constructor args are missing.
// If I omit it, it just adds each cursor object as an instance of stdClass
$opt = ['cursor' => new TestClass];

$results = $m->executeQuery('newDb.testCollection', $query, $opt);

foreach ($results as $document) {
    var_dump($document);
}
```

Is what I want to accomplish possible, or do I need to go through each `stdClass` object and cast it to an instance of `TestClass`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class itself needs to implement the `MongoDB\BSON\Unserializable` interface and the `bsonUnserialize(array $data)` method to convert an array from BSON data into the class in question.

```
class TestClass implements MongoDB\BSON\Unserializable, MongoDB\BSON\Serializable {
    private $id;
    private $name;

    function __construct ($id, $name) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    function bsonUnserialize(array $data) {
        // This will be called *instead* of the constructor if unserializing
        $this->id = $data['_id'];
        $this->id = $data['name'];
    }
}
```

The type map of the `MongoDB\Driver\Cursor` that is returned from the query needs to be set to map a document to an instance of the custom class. The finished code looks like this.

```
$mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager($constr);
$query = MongoDB\Driver\Query(['name' => 'TestFirst']);
$cursor = $mongo->executeQuery($query);
$cursor->setTypeMap('root' => 'array', 'document' => 'TestClass', 'array' => 'array');

foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
    var_dump($doc);
}
```